# Java using multiple methods in the program

Tags: java, oop, methods

I have the following code on Java which works fine now but I'm wondering how to make the same program but with multiple methods (object oriented programming). Right now all the code is in the main method and I'd like to make it so it has at least one other method where the calculations are made and that method would be called in the main method.
The program asks the user different kinds of multiplication questions like 2*3, 9*5 and so on

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random number = new Random();

    while (true) {

        int nmb1 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int nmb2 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int multi = nmb1 * nmb2;
        int question;

        // read the user's input ...
        do {
            question = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is" + nmb1 + "*" + nmb2));

            if (question != multi) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, try again");
            }
        }
        while (question != multi);
        // .. and repeat until the user types the correct answer

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");
      }
   }
}
```

If anyone can offer any help I would appreciate it.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO. Maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be better, but I don't know what their acceptance criteria is. Right now, this question is very much "how do I code in Java?" which is too broad for SO. If this is schoolwork, you should consult with instructors or classmates.

Comment: @jdv:  If you don't know what Code Review's acceptance criteria is, don't even *suggest* it.  Seriously, too much unsuitable stuff goes over there and unless you're ***certain***, suggesting the site only causes *more* unsuitable stuff to go over there.

Comment: I'm not clear as to why you want to use multiple methods here.  This seems to be well-contained and clear, even though it runs in main.

Comment: @Makoto pretending like someone can't find Code Review on their own is just silly. I _clearly_ suggested it as a _resource_ for further study. This whole "don't mention that other SE site" thing is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap up your calculation and user input in a method call multiplication() as shown in the code below. The method will return a boolean value to identify if the user has answer the question correctly. HTH.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      boolean correctAnswer;
      Random number = new Random();
      int nmb1;
      int nmb2;
      int multi;


    while (true) {
        nmb1 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
        nmb2 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
        multi = nmb1 * nmb2;

        // read the user's input ...
        do {
            correctAnswer = multiplication(nmb1,nmb2,multi);
        }
        while (correctAnswer != true);
        // .. and repeat until the user types the correct answer

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");
      }
   }


  public static boolean multiplication(int number1,int number2,int answer)
  {

      int question;

         question = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is" + number1 + "*" + number2));

          if (question != answer) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, try again");

              return false;
          }

      return true;

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, but now the program doesn't repeat the same question again if wrong answer is given.

Comment: I have tried and it does repeat. Can you verify again?

Comment: I pasted it again and it still doesn't work. I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0.

Comment: okay, recopy the code again. I was confuse with the requirement just now. Now it should repeat the same question if the answer is wrong.